# Passing PHP parser errors back in JSON?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have an HTML page that sends a JQuery Ajax call to a PHP page and is expecting a JSON response. If the PHP has a parser error, the error is returned to the call, but not in JSON format, so it ends up throwing a "JSON.parse: unexpected character" error on the Ajax side.

Is there a way to get the PHP to send the error message back in a JSON-friendly format? (Yes, it sends the error to event.log in the PHP file's directory, but I'd rather not have to jump through the hoops of accessing it each time there's a problem with the script.)

Edit: Somebody asked for the code - what I mean is, something like this:

First, the "bad" PHP script, oops.php:

```
<?php
    $x = "There's no terminating semicolon"
    echo json_encode($x);
?>
```

Now, the HTML page that calls it, oops.html:

```
<html>
<head><title>OOPS</title></head>
<body>
<div id="text_goes_here"></div>
</body>

<script>
var $outputText = "Text goes here";

$.ajax({
    url:"oops.php",
    type:"GET",
    data: {},
    success:function(data) {
        outputText = "Success:<br />";
        for (var d in data) {
            outputText += (data[d] + "<br />");
        }
        document.getElementById("text_goes_here").innerHTML = outputText;
    }, 
    error:function(xhr, status, message) {
        outputText = "Error:<br />";
                   + "Status: " + status + "<br />"
                   + "Message: " + message + <br />";
        document.getElementById("text_goes_here").innerHTML = outputText;
    },
    dataType:"json"
});
</script>
</html>
```

The problem appears to be, the PHP returns an error message, but not in a JSON format, so the .ajax call's JSON parser doesn't understand what it is and throws an error of its own. I want to be able to pass the script error that the PHP script generated back to the call in a format that the call can read.

Comment: provide your code, please

Comment: Check out json_encode() at http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: You should make sure your PHP code actually runs as expected before trying to integrate it with ajax.  Will save you a lot of headaches.

Comment: My current "development method" is (a) edit the HTML and PHP files locally (I run WIndows 10), (b) copy the HTML and PHP files to my server, (c) load the HTML page from the server, and (d) see what happens. Can you recommend another method - for example, I hear Eclipse has a PHP development system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use try-catch block.

[This article](https://developer.hyvor.com/php/ajax-request-handler-with-php) shows how to write a AJAX handler with exceptions handled.

Here's the PHP code.

```
<?php
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/inc/ajax.inc.php'; 
try { 
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] !== "POST") {
        throw new Exception('Invalid Request', 2000);
    } else {
        // status is true if everything is fine
        exit(json_encode(
            array(
                'status' => true
            )
        ));
    }
} catch(Exception $e) {

    echo json_encode(
        array(
            'status' => false,
            'error' => $e -> getMessage(),
            'error_code' => $e -> getCode()
        )
    );
    exit;
}
```

And, the JS code:

```
function jsonParse() {
    try {
        var json = JSON.parse(text);
    } 
    catch(e) {
        return false;
    }
    return json;
}

var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var data = "username=" + name + '&email=' + email;

http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var json = jsonParse(this.responseText);

        if (!json || json.status !== true) {
            console.log(json.error || 'Something Bad Happened');
            return;
        }    

        alert('Everything is Fine!');

    }
}

http.open('ajax.php', 'POST', true);
http.send(data);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Using JSON.parse in a try-catch block (and then displaying the unmodified data in the catch) on the JavaScript side worked